# Bootstrap 3 columns and position sticky

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position, sticky

I'm trying to recreate the layout seen at TradingView.com's homepage, where you have 2 columns and once the right column gets to it's bottom the left keeps scrolling. I've tried many things and the closest I can get is the right column being sticky'ed once it hits the top of the view port. Trying to do this without flexbox and completely ripping TradingView's code off.

Have also tried numerous jQuery plugins, including dollarshaveclubs Stickybits and stickying the bottom just isn't working. My html is very simple

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">
     ...
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6"> <!-- sticky this once the last element's bottom hits the viewport -->
     ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Starting to think this can't be done without switching over to flexbox. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Hello for this you can use sticky-kit js. For example : https://codepen.io/zafree/pen/rjvBEg

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you so much! If you make this an answer I'll mark it for you